# Wrong thread finish in C?

Tags: c, multithreading

I compiled this code and the 99th threads that it's been created keeps creating more than one thread of number 99. Instead if i insert values from 1-10 or something small then the results are quite normal.

Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pthread_mutex_t m=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_attr_t attr;

void* test(void *a)
{
    int i=*((int *)a);
    printf("The thread %d has started.\n",i);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
    usleep(10000);
    printf("The thread %d has finished.\n",i);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
    pthread_exit(NULL);

}

int main()
{
    int i=0,j=0;
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr,PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
    pthread_t thread[100];

    for (i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        j=i;
        pthread_create(&thread[i],&attr,test,&j);

    }

    for (i=0;i<100;i++)
        pthread_join(thread[i],NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

i get:

```
..../*Normal Results*/
The thread 99 has finished.
The thread 99 has finished.
The thread 99 has finished.
The thread 99 has finished.
The thread 99 has finished.
The thread 99 has finished.
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: [It seems you already asked a very very similar question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14129675/wrong-thread-ids-in-a-multithreaded-c-program)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep all theadIds

```
int indexes[PTHREAD_COUNT];

for (i=0;i<100;i++) {
    indexes[i] = i;
    pthread_create(&thread[i], &attr, test, &indexes[i]);
}
```

Comment: Also in for threadIdx=i; in for loop.
Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

Each thread is passed the same pointer to the same stack location (`j`) in your main thread.  Without further synchronisation, its undefined when each thread will be scheduled and will run and access `j` before printing its value.

There are lots of ways you could print out a unique number from each thread, including

1. malloc a struct which includes (or is) this number in the main thread.  Pass it to the child threads which are then responsible for freeing it
2. (Suggested by Brian Roche below) Declare an array of 100 ints, with values 0, 1, 2, etc.  Pass the address of a different array item to each thread.
3. have each thread lock a mutex then copy/increment a global counter.  The mutex could be passed into the thread or another global
4. pass a semaphore into each thread, signalling it once the number has been accessed.  Wait on this semaphore in the main thread

Note that options 3 & 4 involve serialising startup of the threads.  There's little point in running multiple threads if you do much of this!

Comment: Actually ... he only has *one j*

Comment: What is the right way to do it?

Comment: @BrianRoach Agreed.  That was what I was trying to say.  If you let me know which part of my answer caused confusion I'll reword it

Comment: @BillSkiadas rather than passing in a reference to j to every thread, allocate a new int, copy in the value of j, and then pass the new int into the thread.

Comment: I think it was mainly reading comprehension on my part :) Although I don't see how this would work period unless you were running one thread after another which ... wouldn't be useful. I'd suggest an array to hold the "ids" or doing the hacky thing where you simply assign the value to j rather than dereferencing it as a pointer

Comment: @BillSkiadas I've updated my answer to mention some of the ways you could get a unique number in each thread

Comment: Sorry if i am bothering you, but can you code the fastest way to do it?
It is really urgent and i really don t have much time.

Comment: option 1 is the fastest way to do this.  I don't mean to be rude but you'll learn more if you try it for yourself rather than having all the code written for you.  It should be easy to implement given the notes so far.

Comment: ^^ Agreed. And if you don't understand pointers and now have an assignment involving threads, I fear this is probably not a good sign that the class is going well as it stands.

Comment: I understand pointers and all. You are not rude, i don t usually ask for code, i enjoy doing it myself, but it just was urgent to finish something tonight and i didn't have the time to finish everything, but anyways. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

`i` is the same address as `j` in your main code, and you sleep of 30 ms in the threads. So all threads have time to run until the first mutex call, then they all stop for (a little over) 30ms, and then print they have finished. Of course, `i` in the main loop is now 99, because you are finished with the pthread_join loop.

You need to have an array of "j" values [assuming you want all threads to run independently]. Or do something else. It all depends on what you are actually wanting to do.

Answer (score 0):

you are passing the same memory location (&j) as the pointer to data a.

when threads start, they print out the value just assigned to j, which looks OK

But then only one get the lock and went to sleep, all others thus blocked. when the nightmare is over, memory location "a", of course, has a int value 99.